# Vuejs - Vuex behavior when committing a property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm noticing a weird behavior in Vuex when I try to mutate a property in the state obj.

Example:

```
Mutation: {
  authUser: (state, payload) => {
   state.email = payload.email
   state.password = payload.password
   ...someOtherProps
}

actions: {
  commit ('authUser', {
    email: 'user@gmail.com'
  })
}
```

What I noticed is that when I commit only one property(in this case "email"), the value of all other properties of the  authUser will be undefined and only email value will be available.

Is that the way Vuex behaves in this case? If yes, how can I avoid the other props not getting a empty value?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're passing an object without a `password` property defined, so it's going to update the `state` object accordingly.

I'd just loop through the properties of the `payload` to update each related `state` object property. And as @82Tuskers pointed out, you'll need to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) if the property in the `payload` object doesn't yet exist on the `state` object (otherwise the property won't be reactive):

```
authUser: (state, payload) => {
  for (prop in payload) {
    if (state.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      state[prop] = payload[prop];
    } else {
      Vue.set(state, prop, payload[prop]);
    }
  }
}
```

This way, only the properties being passed in the `payload` object will be updated on the `state` object.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. But, if you were considering adding new properties to state then you might want to use Vue.set(...) instead of `=`. IMO

Comment: Yep, I was assuming all the properties were already defined on the `state`, but if they aren't then you'd want to use `Vue.set`. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not strange, it is expected behaviour. Just rewrite your mutation this (recommended) way:

```
authUser: (state, payload) => {
  state = Object.assign({}, state, payload)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers seem to fix your issue, it might be worthwhile to put the user-related items into a `user` object inside the state. It is also best practice to establish your state properties up front so you can avoid having to use `Vue.set(...)`:

`state: {
    user: { 
      email: '', 
      password: '' 
    }
}`

...then you could easily avoid looping by using the spread operator: `state.user = { ...state.user, ...payload }` - this essentially says "take everything currently inside `state.user` and merge it with `payload`, overwriting what is in `state.user` with `state.payload`"